# game is crash on S3 in unity 5.4

Tags: unity-game-engine

My game is crash on samsung S3 but not on other devices in unity 5.4. Games is working fine in main menu but when it loads gameplay it will crash only on S3.
i have debug on ddms it shows error like heap_msk=3000000 flags=1,onReceive: android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED –

Comment: That comment shouldn't be a comment but should be part of your question. I would suggest to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42901548/edit) your question and delete the comment.

Comment: Also, have you done any research to help you solve this problem? A search on the error you got for example?

Answer (score 2):

Well it means you are creating too many objects in game play that causing game to crash on low memory devices.

You can sort out this problem by connecting your device and run profiler in unity. That way you can check what causing the problem. If CPU is taking more resources than you need to optimize your code. If overhead is on GPU and if it is a 3d game than you must reduce no of polygons, tris and try to combine meshes and make atlases.

Also you can check if you shaders attached to your camera that will also be visible in profiler. It can tell you that camera render is taking memory.

Hope it helps !